# Storyboard screen and sidebar keeps refreshing in Xcode

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, the storyboard screen and the side bar of any Swift file keeps refreshing. How can I prevent this?

[image: sidebar next to a file in Xcode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sidebar's flickering issue is caused by the constant regeneration of the data while typing in a file and it can be really annoying.

To prevent the refreshing, switch to **the Quick Help inspector**, which actually stays static while typing:

[image: Quick Help inspector]